# Navigation with Drawer

Tags: react-native

I have a component where I have my "Navigation" components combined. Now I want to call navigator.push from my drawer if I press the TouchableHighlight. How is that possibel?

Here is a part of my Code:

```html
/** Combined components (Index.js)

export default class Index extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Drawer>
                <Toolbar />
                <Nav />
            </Drawer>
        )
    }
}
```

```html
/** Drawer (Drawer.js)

export default class Drawer extends Component {
    render() {
            
        var navigationView= (
        <View>
            <TouchableHighlight>
                <Text>Login</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
        )
        
        return (
            <DrawerLayoutAndroid
                draweWidth={300}
                drawerPosition={DrawerLayoutAndroid.positions.Left}
                renderNavigationView={() => navigationView}>
                
                {this.props.children}
                
            </DrawerLayoutAndroid> 
        )
    }
}

/** Toolbar (Toolbar.js)

export default class Toolbar extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ToolbarAndroid
                style={{height: 50}}
                title="App"
            />
        )
    }
}

/**Navigator (Nav.js)

export default class Nav extends Component {
    
    renderScene(route, navigator) {
        switch(route.name) {
            case 'Welcome':
                return <Welcome navigator={navigator} />
            case 'Login':
                return <Login navigator={navigator} />
        }
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <Navigator
                initialRoute={{name: 'Welcome', index: 0}}
                renderScene={(route,navigator) => this.renderScene(route, navigator)}
            />
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use refs and callback functions to achieve that.

On a side note, Navigator is being deprecated in favour of new [API](https://github.com/ericvicenti/navigation-rfc/blob/master/Docs/NavigationOverview.md)

```html
/** Combined components (Index.js)

export default class Index extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Drawer onNavigate={(route) => {
                                 this.refs.nav.push(route)
                               }>
                <Toolbar />
                <Nav ref="nav"/>
            </Drawer>
        )
    }
}
```

```html
/** Drawer (Drawer.js)

export default class Drawer extends Component {
    render() {
            
        var navigationView= (
        <View>
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => {
                                          this.props.onNavigate({name:'Login'});
                                        }}>
                <Text>Login</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
        )
        
        return (
            <DrawerLayoutAndroid
                draweWidth={300}
                drawerPosition={DrawerLayoutAndroid.positions.Left}
                renderNavigationView={() => navigationView}>
                
                {this.props.children}
                
            </DrawerLayoutAndroid> 
        )
    }
}

/** Toolbar (Toolbar.js)

export default class Toolbar extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ToolbarAndroid
                style={{height: 50}}
                title="App"
            />
        )
    }
}

/**Navigator (Nav.js)

export default class Nav extends Component {
    
    renderScene(route, navigator) {
        switch(route.name) {
            case 'Welcome':
                return <Welcome navigator={navigator} />
            case 'Login':
                return <Login navigator={navigator} />
        }
    }
    
    push(route) {
        this.refs.navigator.push(route);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Navigator ref="navigator"
                initialRoute={{name: 'Welcome', index: 0}}
                renderScene={(route,navigator) => this.renderScene(route, navigator)}
            />
        )
    }
}
```